# If Statement to fill a cell based on other cells

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have an excel document that I want to **populate the value `Y` for each title row in column B, based on whether the cells below it have the value "y" or "Y" in it.**

Since each Title row [row that shows an * in it] will have a random amount of questions below it, I am looking for a formula that I will have to manually tweak for each title group.

**Where there is a "" in row B:** that represents the empty value that needs to change to a Y based on whether the questions' column B, below the title, has one or more "y"s

Example

```
Column#       A                                        B
  1       **Services**                                " "
  2       Will this be for internal?                   y
  3       Will you need a vendor?                      N
  4       Does this task require an I/O?               N

  5       **Installation**                            " "
  6       Physical installation?                       Y
  7       Will this take more than 2 hours?            Y
```

I tried something like

=IF(B2="Y" or B2="y" or B3="Y" or B3="y" or B4="Y" or B4="y", B1="Y")

for first Title `Services` but I get an error of it not being properly formatted.

Any suggestions?

---

**Update [FIXED]:**

I wanted to get this part of the function to work so that when I concatenate, it will work since B will be filled in [in my actual version B is D]

=IF(OR(D14="y", D15="y", D16="y"), "Y", "")

```
and when I concatenate in G column to copy the strings in the cells my concatenate formula works :)

=IF(D13="Y",CONCATENATE(B13," | ",C13," | ",F13),"")
```

Comment: there is the OR function, so "=IF(OR(B2="Y",B2="y",B3="Y",B3="y"),"Y",""), but there's also probably a nicer solution someone will come up with :)

Comment: The OR function can be used wherever a condition is required - like as the first parameter of the IF.

Comment: Set cell B1 to the "=IF" statement in my first comment :)

Comment: OR Statement worked for me. Thanks [first time using OR surprisingly haha because I don't use excel functions as much as I should]

Comment: @racraman if you would like, you can add an answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: Glad to help - thanks for that.  After I learnt about OR and AND functions, the next ones that really helped me were VLOOKUP and SUMIF (and SUMIFS), worth getting familiar with to know what's available

Comment: I guess my question was too simple that it got down graded :/ kind of not fair since I asked a question that I did in fact not know how to do.

Comment: O.o I clarified it a few times. Not sure how much more I can do to make it clear @pnuts

Comment: @pnuts does my bold text clarify more??? - see update

Comment: sorry I don't know what IMO stands for @pnuts

Comment: @pnuts no there is no blank row as expressed by the fact that I don't give it a row number. I just gave space so readers could understand they are separate "groups".

Comment: @pnuts that is why I wanted a manual set up like what racraman gave me to manually choose which columns under the titles I wanted to query on. Each title has a random amount of questions underneath it so this was my best route to take as expressed in my example formula above. I will try to clean up my question I guess.

Comment: @pnuts I updated my question to make more sense(not sure how else to word it). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the OR function, so set cell B1 to :

```
=IF(OR(B2="Y",B2="y",B3="Y",B3="y"),"Y","")
```

Comment: Not sure why yours got downgraded too since you did give me an answer close to what I was trying to do. I gave you a 1 since I didn't feel that you deserved the -1 either. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`=IIF(COUNTIF(B2:B4;"y")>0;"Y";"")`

This accounts for Uppercase and Lowercase "Y".

Comment: Thanks for this because it would help shorten my listing; however, I did test without "Y" in the formula and it seems that when you do B2="y" it accounts for lowercase and uppercase :)

Comment: Not only shorten it. If you later want to add a line to any of the questions it is far easier to manage. (Click in the cell and it shows you the range, adjust the range with the mouse...) - if you insert a line IN BETWEEN the already covered lines it will include this line automaticcally.

Comment: @pnuts: ?.. yes. Put this Formula in an Excel-Cell and the cell reads either "Y" or "". That was the goal